# Amazon EC2 Matlab parallel worker

Tags: matlab, amazon-ec2, parallel-processing

I would like to ask those of you having more experience than me in working with Matlab on Amazon EC2 what instance types you prefer?

Using the Parallel Computing Toolbox I want to use as many workers as possible to speed up my code.

I've tested c4.4xlarge with 12 workers and c4.8xlarge with 18 workers in parallel. This is already better than my private PC with only 8 workers, but knowing that providers like [Techila](http://www.techilatechnologies.com/) claim that they can offer 1000x Matlab acceleration by using EC2 I am wondering what instance type would be most suitable for parallel computing.

[edit1]
I have installed Matlab directly on the EC2 instance in order to utilize all available cores. I know there is the possibility to execute "local" code in the cloud, by using EC2 instances as a cluster. But this is currently not what I am aiming for. Just one EC2 instance with Matlab installation. But which instance type do you think is the best? High number of vCPUs should be good, right?

[edit2]
Thx Edric. As I am using an instance type with theoretically 18 (c4.4xlarge) or 36 (c4.8xlarge) vCPUs I think I can turn up the workers to 18 or 36. There is even a (very expensive) instance type with 128 vCPUs available. I set the local cluster profile accordingly and running code without any problems so far.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can only have 12 workers before you need to purchase a different type of license.

Comment: Interesting, because the max I have already reached was 18. I had 18 workers when using the c4.8xlarge, which theoretically provides 36 vCPUs. So I guess there must be a limitation in max workers, but it seems to be 18 rather than 12. But I am sad to hear that an extra license is required.

Comment: That may be true, they occasionally change the maximum number of workers depending upon the release. See some relevant info [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parallel-pools.html#bufclig-1)

Comment: Thank you Suever for your quick reply. I've edited the question, because I think there is a difference whether you want to use a EC2 cluster or simply run a dedicated Matlab installation on one single EC2 instance. The question aims more for are suggestion of the most suitable instance type. Thank you

Comment: @Suever the 12-local-worker limit was removed quite a while ago. These days, with MATLAB + PCT, you can run as many local workers as you wish (I think the limit is 512 or so). The *default* is to run as many local workers as you have cores, but you can oversubscribe the cores by editing the local cluster profile.